# jquery facebook like autosuggest

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm trying to implement an autosuggest similar to the below image in that it has *multiple categories* (eg Countries, Cities).

My ideal solution would be one autosuggest box that populates its *n* different categories via *n* different ajax calls using two different API endpoints.

The only place I've seen this done is facebook's main search box "Search people, places, and things".

I grabbed the below image from this website - http://www.web2ajax.fr/examples/facebook_searchengine/ - but there's no documentation for it and before trying to reinvent/reverse engineer the wheel, I figured I would see if anyone knew of an existing plugin for this.

[image: Autosuggest example]

Thanks!
djs22

Comment: oh wow, I have no idea how I missed this. All of my current implementations use jquery UI but I somehow overlooked this option in the docs

Comment: @Dom If you'd like to add your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For autocomplete categories, go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories (CLICK ON "VIEW SOURCE" BELOW THE DEMO). Also make sure to use themeroller for custom themes: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller.